# Linux Block the LinEnum.sh Tool from Being Used to Escalate Privileges

Tags: linux, security, permissions

I'm looking into how I can stop the LinEnum.sh tool from being used to escalate privileges on Linux boxes where I work. This issue was raised as a result of a pen test.

Is there anyone here who can help?

I think that the issue is more to do with the results of running this tool than being able to run it, itself, but security are asking to block it.

Comment: What was the **actual** issue raised? This script basically just takes an inventory of the system and any obvious vulnerabilities, and there are probably countless such scripts. You can't "block" it that way. This also means that you need to fix the **real** vulnerability, not try to stop water with a sieve.

Comment: Hi Michael, I found out the security guy just wants it removed. I can mark your response as an answer if you like or do you prefer for me to remove this post?